# How to know what version of assertEquals to use

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit, import

I'm working on an app in Kotlin on Android Studio.
When working on a test, and I type "assertEquals" the method name is shown in red. If I type alt+enter, I get a choice of 3 versions.

```
assertEquals(String, Object, Object) (of junit.framework.assert)
assertEquals(String, Object, Object) (of junit.framework.testcase)
assertEquals(String, Object, Object) (of org.junit.assert)
```

How does one know which to choose?

Comment: FWIW, I use the `org.junit.assert` one.

Comment: I'm following a tutorial and actually tried all three. They all failed on a working app, so I'm still lost on it. Trying again with the tutorial's own "solution code" to see if it makes a difference. The tutorial didn't seem to expect there to be a choice.

Comment: Being on Kotlin, I use the `assertEquals` from Kotlin's standard library `kotlin.test`. Reference [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/kotlin.test/kotlin.test/assert-equals.html).

Comment: "They all failed on a working app" -- I am uncertain what you mean by "failed". Do you mean "failed to compile"? Do you mean "the test failed when I ran it"? If the latter, the problem is unlikely to be tied to your specific `import` and more likely to be tied to something about the test or the code being tested.

Comment: It turns out that I needed to import org.junit.assert and change my dependancy from nav_version = "2.3.1" to nav_version = "2.4.2".